# Lie correspondence and functor Lie

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am looking for a simple  proof regarding the fact that the assignmaent $Lie:G \rightarrow Lie(G)$ is functor from $LG$ the category of Lie groups to the category $LA$ of Lie algebras.

In fact I'm looking for any information about the Lie correspondence,for my final exam.
Can you help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is just differentiation at the unitary of G. and also with Lie Deriviative (derivative of derivative of conjugate representation) you have the [,] product over Lie(G).